# Uniform initialization on a vector of vectors of integers

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, curly-braces, uniform-initialization

**C++11**

The program initializes a `vector`, named `myVec`, of `int` `vector`s, and then uses a loop to print out each inner `vector`'s elements. But I got unexpected results when trying to see what happens when I use extra curly braces. The following is also on [this LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/27B5oG%240) for easy toggling between compilers. `g++ 4.8.0` only compiles up to `myVec[5]`. `clang++ 3.2` compiles everything:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVec =
    {
        /* myVec[0] */ {1, 2},
        /* myVec[1] */ {},
        /* myVec[2] */ {{}},
        /* myVec[3] */ { {}, {} },
        /* myVec[4] */ { {}, {}, {} },
        /* myVec[5] */ {{{}}}

        /* myVec[6] */  // , { {{}}, {{}} }       // g++ 4.8.0 COMPILER ERROR
        /* myVec[7] */  // , {{{{}}}}             // g++ 4.8.0 COMPILER ERROR
        /* myVec[8] */  // , { {{{}}}, {{{}}} }   // g++ 4.8.0 COMPILER ERROR
    };

    // loop for printing
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "myVec[" << i << "]: ";
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < myVec.at(i).size(); ++j)
        {
            std::cout << myVec.at(i).at(j) << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Actual `g++ 4.8.0` output:**

```
myVec[0]: 1, 2,
myVec[1]:
myVec[2]: 0,
myVec[3]: 0, 0,
myVec[4]: 0, 0, 0,
myVec[5]: 0,
```

**Analysis:**

**`myVec[0]` : `{1, 2}` :**

Got expected output.

**`myVec[1]` : `{}` :**

Got expected output.

**`myVec[2]` : `{{}}` :**

This is a vector of the `int` `0`. The inner brace initializes an `int` to `0`.

**`myVec[3]` : `{ {}, {} }` :**

The two inner braces initializes an `int` each to `0`.

**`myVec[4]` : `{ {}, {}, {} }` :**

The three inner braces initializes an `int` each to `0`.

**`myVec[5]` : `{{{}}}` :**

I wanted to add yet another set of curly braces to `myVec[2]` to see how far I can go with adding braces before getting compiler errors. I don’t understand why this compiles and why its element prints as `0`.

For example, `int j = {}` initializes `j` to `0`. `vector<vector<int>> v = { {{}} }` initializes the innermost `{}` to `int` `0`, making it equivalent to `vector<vector<int>> v = { {0} }`. Then, what is `vector<vector<int>> u = { {{{}}} }` and why would it compile?

**The Hypothetical `myVec[6]` : `{ {{}}, {{}} }` :**

Following the same pattern as above, I wanted to make a vector that contains two sets of double curly braces. But this doesn’t compile, and I don’t understand why this breaks the pattern of giving me multiple zeroes.

**The Hypothetical `myVec[7]` : `{{{{}}}}` :**

I wanted to add yet another set of curly braces to `myVec[5]` to see how far I can go with adding braces before getting compiler errors. I don’t understand why this breaks the pattern and doesn't compile.

**The Hypothetical `myVec[8]` : `{ {{{}}}, {{{}}} }` :**

I wanted to extend `myVec[7]` to to make a vector with two sets of triple braces. I don't understand why this doesn't compile either.

If everything up to `myVec[5]` compiles, why doesn't the rest?

Comment: For the `{{}, {}}` case, think of the inner `{}`s being initializers for the `int`s, where their default constructor is called, giving them a value of `0`. As for `{{{}}}`, I have no idea.

Comment: [With clang, every line compiles, albeit with warnings.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2VasjA$0)

Comment: @Mankarse do [1]-[4] warn or just [5]-[8]?

Comment: @StephenLin: Just 5-8.

Comment: I have the same question as `Xymostech`. If for `{{}, {}}`, the inner `{}`s are initializers for `int`s that initialize to `0`s, then what would an extra set of curly braces, as in `{{{}}}`, mean? Is clang's ability to compile `{{{}}}` a bug, or is my GCC 4.7.1 compiler supposed to be able to compile `{{{}}}`?

Comment: @CodeBrinks the warning for me with clang is `too many braces around scalar initializer` so presumably it's illegal but clang is just letting you get away with it. GCC accepting [5] without warning seems to be a bug (or possibly an "extension" :D)

Comment: @CodeBricks I think code example shows that if they allow {{1}} accepted as initializer for int, then f() cannot be resolved in main() - both variants should be accepted. I am not sure what you mean by self referencing - that statement defines struct B with ctor accepting int.

Comment: @Slava: My mistake about the self-reference, so I deleted that part. But the `struct`'s ctor in `struct B { B(int); };` is missing a definition. Shouldn't it be `struct B { B(int) {} };` ? Is that what's causing the compiler error?

Comment: @CodeBricks existence of definition of B::B() is irrelevant to that code sample, it does not need to be linked as it used to check if code would produce compilation errors or not.

Comment: @Slava: Thanks. My mistake. I meant it will be another error had there not been ambiguity in overload resolution when compiling with both `A` and `B`. I updated the part.

Comment: -1: I'm sure it's a great question and an interesting story and all, but this is just waaaay too long.

Comment: Answers should not be in the question; nor should they be copied into the question. Your question is way too long to be useful to anyone else; please pare it down to its essentials (e.g., get rid of everything that isn't actually a question or directly supports the **one** question you're asking).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to compile this code. it should explain your issue:

```
int i = {};   // initializes i to int()
int j = {{}}; // fails to compile
```

why `{{{}}}` is accepted in your code seems to be a gcc bug(needs to clarify) related how ctor is processed:

```
struct foo {
    foo( std::initializer_list<int> ) {}
};
void f()
{
   foo bar1( {{{}}} ); // compiles fine
   foo bar2 = {{{}}}; // compiles fine
}
```

Edit (thanks to Johannes Schaub) - deleting copy ctor makes first variant uncompilable:

```
struct foo {
    foo( std::initializer_list<int> ) {}
    foo( const foo& ) = delete;
};
void f()
{
   foo bar1( {{{}}} ); // fails to compile: use of deleted function ‘foo::foo(const foo&)’
   foo bar2 = {{{}}}; // still compiles, neither deleting move ctor, nor assignment operator does not affect that, is copy ctor of std::initializer_list involved?
}
```

for member function it fails:

```
struct foo {
    void moo( std::initializer_list<int> ) {}
};
void f()
{
   foo bar;
   bar.moo( {{{}}} ); // fails to compile
}
```

This code fails as well:

```
std::initializer_list<int> l = {{{}}}; // fails to compile
```

Same situation ctor vs member function for std::vector:

```
void f()
{
    std::vector<int> v( {{{}}} ) // compiles fine;
    v.assign( {{{}}} ); // fails to compile
};
```

gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)

Comment: I'm not OP, but the second doesn't compile for me (it doesn't seem like it should), which doesn't seem to explain why `{{{}}}` can initialize a `vector<int>` in his [5] case.

Comment: My compiler is just giving me a warning no matter how many braces I put.

Comment: (gcc 4.7.2 here, his [5] case compiles for me but `int j = {{}}` doesn't)

Comment: Ah, you're right. clang 3.3 is fine with everything, just gives a ton of warnings.

Comment: I used Code::Blocks 12.11 with the GCC 4.7.1 32-bit compiler.

Comment: `std::vector<int> v = {{{}}}` works without warning but `std::vector<int> v = {{{{}}}}` errors.

Comment: @CodeBricks you understand why `std::vector<int> v = {{}}`,`std::vector<int> v = {{}, {}}`, etc. work right? Uniform initialization applies to built-in types like `int` too.

Comment: @StephenLin yes you are right, I missed example with {{{}}}, it seem to relate how gcc process std::initializer_list<T> versus embedded type.

Comment: Interesting that std::initializer_list<int> l = {{{}}}; fails to compile.

Comment: `int j = {{}};` doesn't compile on GCC 4.7.1, which gives `error: braces around scalar initializer for type 'int'`

Comment: @CodeBricks yes that is not expected to compile, sorry will add comments to clarify

Comment: For me `{{{}}}` just shouldn't work, period. It can be read as initializer list of integers which should be initialized with empty initializer list. A bridge too far, imho. On the other hand `{{{}}}` in a ctor might be treated as `vector` of `int`s, initialized with a initializer list composed of one `int` default initialized using a brace initialization.

Comment: The reason is probably because GCC incorrectly accepts the copy and move constructors in constructing a temporary `foo` object, thereby "slurping" up the brace, and then making the brace-reduced list eligible for initialization with the initialization list constructor. Clang did that too some time ago, see http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12117

Comment: Note that accepting `foo bar1( {{{}}} );` is fine - this is not forbidden by the spec, but if you replace the round parens by braces, it becomes invalid for the mentioned reason of not being able to use the copy and move ctors.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb thanks, for foo bar1( {{{}}} ); copy ctor is involved, do you have an idea why foo bar2 = {{{}}}; compiles?